# What to download to use MDC Web offline in a PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, offline, mdc-components, material-components-web

I want to use MDC Web (https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/) in a PWA offline.

What am I supposed to download? Where is the official documentation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either follow the getting started guide to generate your own javascript and css files (So you can customise colour, shape etc) [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#installing-locally). (This is the recommended way)

Or you can just download and copy the CDN JS & CSS files [here](https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@6.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js) (JS) and [here](https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@6.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css) (CSS)
The CDN versions only use the default colour and shape and you cant change it that much.

Comment: Thanks, that was the info I was looking for. I'm surprised that the CDN version is not easy to customise.